# Pulling a value from one table and using it in a joint calculation

Tags: dax

I have a typical sales database with the day to day sales information.  Date, Customer, product code, Product Description, quantity, total sales value etc etc.  I also have a master product list, product code, product description, list price, etc, etc.

There is a relationship between the two tables(linked by product code).

I want to pull the list price from the product table and compare the selling price against it, showing the variance against the list price.  There will be multiple occurrences of the same product on a day, bioought by multiple customers. Can this be done with a measure or does it have to be a calculated column?

Cheers

Tried calculating a sum of the list price and averaging its unit value.